# Reboot a server and sign into a program

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scripting, automation

I have a client who is a medical clinic and their main server, running server 2008 r2, has a program that shuttles labs from their lab vendor to their EMR/EHR.

I am currently automatically rebooting all the

Is there a way for the server to reboot, automatically launch AND log into the lab interface?  The interface is not a service that runs, but just a program that runs in the system tray.

I have also checked with the vendor and there is not a command switch that can be ran in order to log in.

Comment: AutoIt or AutoHotKey might do the trick.

Comment: Why are you rebooting their servers weekly? If you need to reboot them in order for them to function properly then there's a larger problem that needs solving.

Comment: not necessarily. Or - yes, but.... guess what, medical and financial software often is as crappy as it can get, and fixing third party software is not something an admin can do. Rebooting on weekends works there, or as precaution (we reboot our trading infrastructure on weekends, too, to make sure things are good and enable patching at this point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for the server to reboot, automatically launch AND log into the lab 
>   interface?

Kios mode. Auto-Login can be done with registry keys (including the password there) and you can then either use a logon script to start the program, or replace the shell with it (so called Kiosk mode).

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/207ef293-2a5c-461a-aafb-630caacd3d56/enforcing-kiosk-mode-via-gpo-or-other-methods

Any competent admin would know it is not on the software vendor to provide auto logon when this is already part of windows.

Auto-Login is described at:

http://www.expta.com/2008/04/how-to-enable-autologon-for-windows.html